# Return first n values of associative PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a PHP array which after sorting looks like:

```
Array ( [542] => 30 [588] => 29.77 [409] => 19.9 [237] => 19.47 [457] => 17.73 [410] => 15.86);
```

The actual array is quite long. Initially, the keys were set sequentially like 0, 1, 2...
Then I sorted the array and now the array looks like the array above. When I tried to print the first element if this sorted array using echo `$engagement[0]`, I did not get the value 30. To get 30 I had to use `$engagement[542]`. But I have no way of knowing what might be the first key in this sorted array. How can I print first n key and value pairs of this sorted array?

Let me know if I need to be more clear with my explanation. :)

Comment: you need to had a trick, try `$keys = array_keys($engagement);` loop through the `$keys` and access main array. For 30 just use: `$engagement[$keys[0]]`

Comment: have you tried `foreach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `array_slice()` for slice your array at a fixed length and then use `array_keys`.

```
$length = 50;
$start = 0;
$new_arr = array_slice($engagement, $start, $length);
$keys = array_keys($new_arr);
foreach($keys as $key){
    echo $new_arr[$keys[$key]];
}
```

Without the `array_keys`:

```
foreach($new_arr as $key => $value){
    echo $key." => ".$value;
}
```

Remember to use `true` when you don't use the `array_keys` like:

```
$new_arr = array_slice($engagement, $start, $length, true);
```

More about: [array_slice](https://php.net/array_slice)

> If you don't use the true the slice array index will be reset and you
> lose the keys.

**Updates:**

As you are asking for only the array keys, By default array_slice reset the array keys, if you want to preserve then you need to use true as the forth parameter of array_slice.

```
$new_arr = array_slice($engagement, $start, $length, true);
$keys = array_keys($new_arr); // here is the list of the keys
```

Comment: Thanks Frayne. What do I need to change if I want the keys and not the values?

Comment: simply `array_keys` will give you the keys of that array. `$keys = array_keys($new_arr);`

Comment: That gave me 0,1,2,3,4,5... :)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this ...

```
$test = array('29.58', '21.78', '56.258', '10.145', '98.23', '20', '78.32', '112', '5.64', '55.26');
asort($test);

$count = 0;
foreach($test as $key => $val)
{
    if($count <=5)
    {
        echo " [".$key."] => ".$val."\t";
        $count+=1;
    }
}
```